# How to make a binary mask of the image, with highlighted by hand contours OpenCV?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, contour

I want to make a binary image mask where the outside of the selected polygon is 0 and the inside is 1.
How to select only those parts of the image that I have highlighted?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ii2nW.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHafa.jpg)

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('data/baba.jpg')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, im = cv2.threshold(img_gray, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
contours, hierarchy  = cv2.findContours(im, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
#print('hierarchyL', hierarchy)
print("The Total Number of Contours in the Image = ")
print (str(len(contours)))
#print(contours[0])
cnt = contours[0]
con_num=0
# print and draw all contours
for con in contours:
    cv2.drawContours(image, contours, con_num,(0,2550,0),2, cv2.LINE_AA, hierarchy, 2 )
    cv2.drawContours(img_gray, contours, con_num,(0,255,0),2)
    cv2.imwrite(f'data_new/image_thres_{con_num}.jpg', image)
    cv2.imwrite(f'data_new_gray/image_thres_{con_num}.jpg', img_gray)
    con_num=con_num+1

mask = np.zeros(image.shape,np.uint8)
cv2.drawContours(mask,[cnt],0,255,-1)
cv2.imwrite(f'data_new/mask.jpg', mask)
pixpoints = np.transpose(np.nonzero(mask))
pixpoints = cv2.findNonZero(mask)
print ("The original image is: ")
cv2.imshow('Image', mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
raise SystemExit
```

Comment: Invert your mask.

Comment: You are drawing white (255) filled contours on a black (0) background.  Draw 1 filled contours on black (0) background and then invert. Or draw black (0) filled contours on a 1 background.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Load the image
image = cv2.imread('data/baba.jpg')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Threshold the image
ret, im = cv2.threshold(img_gray, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

# Find contours
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(im, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Select the first contour (you can choose any other)
cnt = contours[0]

# Create an empty mask
mask = np.zeros_like(im)

# Draw the filled contour on the mask (inside will be 1)
cv2.drawContours(mask, [cnt], -1, 1, thickness=cv2.FILLED)

# Display the mask
cv2.imshow('Mask', mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

We find the contour of the selected polygon, assuming the first contour (contours[0]) in this case.
Then, create an empty mask with the same size as the image.
We can draw the filled contour on the mask, setting the inside to 1.

The mask image will have 0s outside of the selected polygon and 1s inside it. You can adjust the contour selection logic if you want to work with a different polygon.

Comment: Thank you
but the code only outputs a black mask for any outline?
He doesn't see the drawn outline he made.
what am I doing wrong? please help

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzPEJ.jpg